# PHP How to settle registration input errors?

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I maded registration script, and know I dont have a idea, how to settle input errors to dont insert data in db. Know I maded, that errors during registration(empty inputs, password matching, etc) echo's on new page and die'ing all. Its pretty cool.

But how do it using creating variables with info, and echo it later (for place upper the inputs) and at the same time dont allow the inserting any input data into DB tables.

Code: hosted on safe code-paste site, dont be shy and open http://paste.laravel.com/M1H , edit please someone, who can insert code below :) Thanks anyway

- Bad

Comment: You need to not use mysql_ extension either as it is unsafe, you need to use PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, assuming you're posting a value stored in an element with id input1:

```
$notEmpty = isset($_POST['input1']) && !empty($_POST['input1']);
if($notEmpty)
{
    // Do db call.
}
else
{
    // Display errors.
}
```

You should get the basic idea, Google will teach you more.